# OR operator in Find By Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to use OR Operator in doctrine with find by and do not want to use a query builder.

```
return $this->repository->findBy(
        array('status' => 1, 'flag' =>1, 'contentType' => 'news'),
        array('created' => 'DESC'),
        $limit
    );
```

I want this query run like staus 1 OR flag 1 But It's run like AND operator.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably won't be much of a help to you, since you don't want to resort to `QueryBuilder` but I'll post it anyway in case you change your mind, because I haven't seen a way to add this kind of conditions to `findBy`.

Since `EntityRepository` implements `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Selectable` you can add `Criteria` to further filter/find your results. The cool thing about the API is that it supports `repository`, `collections` and `lazy collections`.

Simply, adding `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;` at top of Repository file, we can then define a separate method for more clarity defining our criteria, like this:

```
public function addStatusOrFlagCriteria() {
    $expr = Criteria::expr();
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria
        ->where(
            $expr->orX(
                $criteria->expr()->eq('flag', 1),
                $criteria->expr()->eq('flag', 0)
            )
        )
        ->orderBy(array('id' => 'ASC'))
    ;

    return $criteria;
}
```

Then, judging by how you call your repository methods, using this criteria would be like:

```
$result = $this->repository->matching( 
    $this->repository->addStatusOrFlagCriteria() 
);
```

Which would return `Doctrine\ORM\LazyCriteriaCollection`

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine doesn't support `OR` operations in its `findBy()` method by default. You have two options:

1. Extend your `$this->repository` to contain your own custom `findBy` method that will support `OR` operations however you please. More details [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories)
2. Use `QueryBuilder` / `DQL` / raw `SQL` to run your query directly.

Unfortunately both methods will include writing some sort of query language. I personally find the `QueryBuilder` a bit messy, especially for more complex queries, so I'd advise starting with plain `DQL` if you're new to it!